# Surprising result using operator form of FoldList

Tags: list-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation, functional-style

I was trying to implement some Graph related functions in Functional form and came accross this result which I found surprising.

I want a function that does various operations on a graph.

The simplest operation is Identity which could simply count the number of nodes in the graph.

Somehow this function does exactly that.

```
Fold[1 + #&][1,{a,b,c,d}]
```

giving:

> ```
> 5
> ```

And the corollary result which shows how it works:

```
FoldList[1 + #&][1,{a,b,c,d}]
```

giving:

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
> ```

The two questions that arise are:

1. Can this result be explained in an intuitive fashion ?
2. Can this idea be used to perform more complex operations on the graph ?

Comment: Did you forget a `}`? Or did you have a `{` too much?

Comment: [FoldList >> Properties and Relations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldList.html) : _**Functions that ignore their second argument give the same result as in NestList**_. Similarly for `Fold`.

Comment: @C.E. Thanks for pointing this out. I removed the superfluous `{`.

Comment: @kglr Ah yes, reading the docs. Thanks a lot. I learned my first lesson the hard way ! Althouth this is such an obfuscated way to count the length of a list :-P